# Google AppEngine dev app server won't run on localhost

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, localhost, google-cloud-endpoints, dev-appserver

I'm using Eclipse Java EE and when I compile and run my Google AppEngine project on `localhost:8080` the browser doesn't give any correct output, but when I'm using `127.0.0.1:8080` my program runs on the browser just fine. But when I deploy my app to the google appspot then the `localhost:8080` will updated and works well ( only for the instance that I deployed to the appspot ).

Why `localhost:8080` won't update right and `127.0.0.1:8080` update right?

I can't use `127.0.0.1:8080` insted localhost always because when I try to get the `_ah/api/explorer` then `127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/api/explorer` will redirect to the google apis explorer ( not to my api explorer).

What should I do to get this right?

Comment: Could be an IPv4 vs. IPv6 issue. Does your `/etc/hosts` file have IPv6 entries for `localhost`?

Comment: nope I guess not, l1>> 127.0.0.1 localhost sandbox.dev
l2>> 127.0.0.1 localhost these are the two entries that I recently added and these won't do any good either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the parameter :

```
--address=...
```

The host address to use for the server. You may need to set this to be able to access the development server from another computer on your network. An address of 0.0.0.0 allows both localhost access and hostname access. Default is localhost.

More on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver?csw=1).

Comment: I think it's related to the version, but I had to use --host=0.0.0.0, anyway, you put me on the rail ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would have just added this as a comment to the accepted answer, but I don't have enough reputation points yet.

The above answer is 100% correct, but an alternative to starting it with the flag, is to edit the pom.xml.  Near the bottom of mine was this.  I had to uncomment the "address" line and... magic... http://localhost:8080/ started working again. Now I just wish I had those 3 hours back.  :D

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    {snip}
    <configuration>
        {snip}
        <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all -->
        <!-- IPs instead of just localhost -->
        <address>0.0.0.0</address>
        <port>8080</port>
        {snip}
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Here is where I found the original.  Scroll to the very bottom:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven/blob/master/pom.xml